# How to diplay tag link in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

After every post I am displaying tags

```
<?php
 global $post;
 foreach(get_the_tags($post->ID) as $tag) {
  echo '<li>'.$tag->name.'</li>';
  }
?>
```

Now I need to display tag not just as text but as a link that would display *all posts filtered by given tag*, just like on stackoverflow when you click a tag below the question.

1. How to make it?
2. What page template will be used to display search results?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
<?php
global $post;
foreach(get_the_tags($post->ID) as $tag)
{
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_tag_link($tag->term_id) . '">' . $tag->name . '</a></li>';
}
```

What page template will be used to display search results : for the search template you can [follow me](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page) for the tags template [Tag_Template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Tag_Templates)

Comment: Right, will it be rendered using index.php loop or do I have to provide some other search template page for that?

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="<?php echo get_tag_link($tag_id); ?>">tag name</a>
```